# How can I use preg_replace in wordpress theme settings panel to get post title or tags

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't understand how do you use the preg_replace command in php

I created a text area in theme settings panel to display a default description for every post and would be nice if I can mix the description using {tags} or {title} to grab the post title or post tags.

I have tried using the following code but got some errors.

description code

```
$description = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'field_description', true); if(!empty($description)) {

$seo_desc = get_option('mytheme_seo_description');

echo $description; 

} else if(!empty($seo_desc)) {

echo $seo_desc;
```

setting panel

```
$options[] = array( "name" => __('SEO DESCRIPTION','mytheme'),
"desc" => __('Mix {title} {tags} {categories} in a default description to grab post title, tags and categories','mytheme'),
"id" => $shortname."_seo_description",
"std" => "",
"type" => "textarea");
```

Is it possible to use {title} {tags} {categories} for grabbing the post title,tags and categories using any function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I just got it using str_replace

```
$description = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'field_description', true);
if(!empty($description)) {

$seo_desc = get_option('mytheme_seo_description');
$seo_desc = str_replace("{title}", $post->post_title, $seo_desc);
echo $description; 

} else if(!empty($seo_desc)) {

echo $seo_desc;
```

I was using the wrong variable 
but it was just a pice of code

```
 $seo_desc = str_replace("{title}", $post->post_title, $seo_desc);
```

So now I can use {title} in textarea in the theme settings panel to get the post title
thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

You could write some [shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to do that. The only difference is that it will target [title/tags/etc] instead of {title/tags/etc} and it **should** be able to parse them automatically if they are used.

Comment: the shortcodes are not supported in my framework theme settings panel

Comment: You'd have to write them into your functions.php file.

Comment: anyway I couldnt do anything Im looking about the str_replace in google but I couldnt get it working yet